# Create a Report Based On a Parameter Query

Tags: ms-access, crosstab

I have an Access application that has been running for years now. It's a payroll system. There's a query (let's call it Query3) that pulls data from 2 crosstab queries. Everything worked fine until when I introduced a parameter in the crosstab queries. The parameter refers to a date on a form. Now I can't create a report with Query3 as its record source. When I use Report Wizard and I select Query3 as its record source the field names are not displayed. I have a sub that programmatically creates a report based on Query3 but now with the parameter this fails too. I'm really stumped. Is there any workaround? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: In Access cross-tabs bug with any amount of complication.  Here is a solution that should work and actually solves a host of other problems.  Replace all references to the form's parameter with a call to a function like getMyParameter.  if you don't have one, add a code module and add public functions like: getMyParameter and setMyParameter.  add a private myparameter to the module or better yet a settings table with myparamter. Yes, were synthesizing a property.  when the form loads and in the queries call getMyParameter.  in the form afterUpdate event call setMyParameter.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Forms!MyForms!MyControl syntax as the parameter in the Crosstab subs? The problem seems to be related to Access not finding the control .
One thing I have done in the past is, if possible, is to remove the crosstab parameters and instead set the SQL of the crosstabs before running the report. So for example:

```
CurrentDB.QueryDefs("CrossTabSubName").SQL - "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE MyParam = 'A'"
```

If you have a button or something that launches the report, this may be an convenient place to do this. If the parameter is on the same form (i.e. a report filter), then this approach is simple to implement. In this example, the value of 'A' is a control on the form that allows th user to filter the report.

Comment: thank you for your response. Yes, I'm using Forms!MyForms!MyControl syntax in the crosstab queries and Query3 opens just fine with filtered records as desired. The problem is I can't create a report with Query3 as its record source. Is it really possible to create a report on a parameter crosstab query?

Comment: They do under certain circumstances (see this http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html, under the "Handling Parameters" topic). I would suggest you build-up and set the QueryDef's SQL just before you runt the report, however. In that model, you are still using a parameter, but not relying on Access to fetch the parameter.